# How much chessed should one be doing?

Tags: shiurim-measurements

Chesed, kindness, is a mitzvah in Judaism.

Say people are coming to you all day asking for favors, should one make an effort to do every favor that is asked or is there a sane limit to how much chesed one should be doing?

I know that with charity the upper limit is 20% of one's income. Is there any such limit with chesed/gemilut chassadim?

Should one take any measure to prevent others from taking advantage of him?

Comment: what do you mean by "sane limit"?

Comment: Recommended reading: Ahavas Chessed by the Chafetz Chaim. Should answer all your questions.

Comment: @ray, that's open to interpretation. My intention was that you shouldn't be left out of breath after doing chessed all day long (or something along those lines).

Answer (score 2):

There is no shiur for *gmilut hassadim* (acts of kindness) as the Mishna says ([Peah 1:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Peah.1.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

> **These are the things that have no measure**: [...] **acts of kindness**, and the study of the Torah. These are
>   things the fruits of which a man enjoys in this world, while the
>   principal remains for him in the World to Come: Honoring one's father
>   and mother, acts of kindness, and bringing peace between a man and his
>   fellow. But the study of Torah is equal to them all.

Now the fact that there is no limit doesn't mean chesed is always first priority. See for instance [here](https://www.shemayisrael.com/rabbiforsythe/interpersonal/chesed.htm#levels)

> If a man is occupied with learning of Torah, his Torah takes
>   precedence. When one is engaged in one mitzva, he is generally
>   exempted from another mitzva. If while learning Torah the opportunity
>   for chesed presents itself, if someone else is able to perform the
>   chesed, the man should not interrupt his study. If, however, no one
>   else is available or willing to perform the chesed, the law (Yora Daya
>   246:18) says to do the chesed. Since the person or cause means that
>   there is need, you are required in order that the need be fulfilled.
>   Then, when the chesed has been accomplished, return to your learning.
>
> If more people request chesed (practical kindness) or tzadaka
>   (charity) than you can provide, there is an elaborate and complex
>   order of priorities which have to be studied or discussed with a Torah
>   scholar. Generally, higher priorities go with the closer relative, the
>   one who dwells in a location more close to you, the greater person in
>   Torah, a Kohain over a Levi over a Yisroel over a momzer, a female
>   over a male, a destitute person over a wealthy person, the greater the
>   measure or suffering or weakness. Since actual cases can be complex
>   (e.g. a talmid chochom momzer is over an ignorant Kohain), a rav must
>   be asked who has the higher the priority.

Comment: Does that Mishna mean there is no upper limit or no lower limit?